# Find the minimum value of a parameter above which a function is unity for positive values of its variable

Tags: equation-solving

I want to find the numerical value of alpha in function

```
(-E^-x α + E^-x x α)^2/(2 (1 - E^-x x α)^2)
```

above which the function is unity for some positive values of x.

Answer is approximately 2.4095.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Why not discuss how you found your approximate answer? We might be able to adapt this to *Mathematica*.

Comment: I can see how you got the value 2.4095 from the image http://i.stack.imgur.com/CpjQO.png, but it also appears not to be the optimal answer to the problem as currently stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expr = (-E^-x α + E^-x x α)^2/(2 (1 - E^-x x α)^2);

ContourPlot[expr == 1, {x, 0, 3}, {α, 0, 4}, FrameLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

The global minimum is at the boundary

```
min1 = NMinimize[{α, expr == 1, x > 0, α > 0}, {α, x}]

(*  {1.41421, {α -> 1.41421, x -> 2.40504*10^-8}}  *)

expr /. {α -> Sqrt[2], x -> 0}

(*  1  *)
```

The local minimum for x > 1

```
min2 = NMinimize[{α, expr == 1, x > 1, α > 1}, {α, x}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 15]

(*  {2.40948624835748, {α -> 2.40948624835748, x -> 1.41421356285863}}  *)
```

The value returned for x is approximately Sqrt[2]

```
min3 = MinValue[{α, (expr /. x -> Sqrt[2]) == 1, α > 
     0}, α] // FullSimplify

(*  -(-2 + Sqrt[2]) E^Sqrt[2]  *)

min3 // N[#, 15] &

(*  2.40948628645477  *)

expr /. {x -> Sqrt[2], α -> min3} // Simplify

(*  1  *)
```

Comment: +1. ContourPlot was used to get the initial idea about the minima. How to proceed initially if one needs to minimize two parameters for positive x, for example in (8 x^(2/3) \[Alpha]^2 (-1 + x^(4/3) \[Beta])^2)/(9 (E^(
   x^(4/3) \[Beta]) - x^(4/3) \[Alpha])^2)

Comment: @Sluth - If you want to minimize two parameters you have to state how you want this done, i.e., define a function of the two parameters to be minimized, e.g., minimize a^2 + b^2. Also you state that x is positive but what are the constraints on the two parameters? Is the expression given in the comment also supposed to equal unity? All of these questions should be included in a new question rather than asking a question in a comment. Note that `ContourPlot3D` can show contours in {x, a, b} space.